# How to overwrite wordpress index styles?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, overriding

Using a child theme in wordpress, my styles are not overwritting styles shown in the index. But they do overwrite parent theme css.

I cant find the original code and ive added the below into functions.php to set child-theme.css as the default stylesheet.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

CSS I'm trying to add but isn't finding -

```
body.custom-background {
 background-size: cover !important; 
}
```

Web inspector not locating child-theme.css -

[image: web-inspector-img]

Comment: There’s two errors indicated, so go check the console … likely your path to the stylesheet is wrong, so you get a 404 …?

Comment: @misorude the errors are just a missing image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by locating the first stylesheet (stack-88 as displayed in image above) and adding the line of code in this file with !important which then overwrote the index styles.